# Google Analytics API: Find Session longer than a minute Pageviews more than one Page

Tags: php, google-analytics

Using the Google Analytics API I'm trying to find a "Quality Visit".

"A Quality Visit occurs when the visitor stays more than one minute and views more than one page."

Right not I'm grabbing rows like this:

```
$results = $this->analytics->data_ga->get(
'ga:'.$this->profileId,
$this->reportStartDate,
$this->reportEndDate,
'ga:sessions,ga:users,ga:pageviews',
array('dimensions' => 'ga:sessionDurationBucket')
    );
```

Counting the Quality Visits like this.

```
 $rows = $results->getRows();
 foreach ($rows as $rowArr)
 {
    // ga:sessionDurationBucket > 59
    // ga:pageviews > 0
    if($rowArr[0] > 59 && $rowArr[3] > 0) 
       $count++;
 }
```

I'm not getting the right number and can't figure out why. Figured it has to do with my lack of knowledge. Any help is appreciated.

*Update* I believe the problem is that out of [ga:sessions] => 8513 I'm only getting [totalResults] => 1359. I was able to increase totalResults substantially by getting each days results individually. [totalResults] => 4899 but I still fall well short of receiving individual Session.

Can anyone confirm that this is because I don't have a 360 or premium account?

Comment: The problem is that out of  [ga:sessions] => 8513 I'm only getting [totalResults] => 1359. I was able to increase totalResults substantially by getting each days results individually. [totalResults] => 4899 but I still fall well short.

Comment: Can anyone confirm that his is because I don't have a 360 or premium account?